# trapping http/https requests in windows

Tags: c#, c++, windows, operating-system, hook

Is it possible to trap http/https requests for filtering in windows?

Comment: HTTPS is designed to protect against man-in-the-middle attacks, which is exactly what you want to do. So any solution is going to be imperfect in that respect.

Comment: just need to trap the URLS and frequency... need to perform different action based on that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to sniff the packets, you could use [Ethereal](http://www.ethereal.com/) or [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)

**Update:**

Try [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) then it gives you a lot of features along with the popular *nix Library libpcap API

Comment: @Umair: winpcap _is_ for programming. read it's documentation: http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/main.html

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a proxy, e.g., [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: Doesn't work too well with HTTPS, of course, but it's scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=983b941d-06cb-4658-b7f6-3088333d062f) is pretty good.  I've used wireshark, and Network Monitor is just as good, if not better.